# Django exclude() query with violation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have this model:

```
class SettingMenus(models.Model):
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Setting, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="menus", null=True)
    index = models.SmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(32766)], default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='sub_categories', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.ManyToManyField(UserRole, related_name="settingMenus", blank=True)
    tables = models.ManyToManyField(AppModels, related_name="setting_menus", blank = True,)
```

And a query in view:

```
nv1menus = SettingMenus.objects.filter(
    cat__company__name=company,
    cat__application="common",
    index=0,
    role__in=request.user.groups.all()
).exclude(sub_categories__role__in=request.user.groups.all()).distinct()
```

How I can violating `sub_categories__role__in=request.user.groups.all()` which is in exclude?

I have tried:

`sub_categories__role__in!=request.user.groups.all()`

or

`not sub_categories__role__in=request.user.groups.all()`

But not works.

### Update:

This model inheritance `Grops` and `Permission` from `django.contrib.auth.models`

```
class UserRole(Group, CommonModel):
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Group Description")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class UserAccess(Permission, CommonModel):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Permission Description")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(verbose_name="About Me", null=True, blank=True)

    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        UserRole,
        verbose_name="User Groups",
        blank=True,
        related_name="users",
        related_query_name="user"
    )

    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        UserAccess,
        verbose_name="User Permissions",
        blank=True,
        related_name="users",
        related_query_name="user"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Here related model for `SettingMenus` model

Comment: Exactly *what* do you want to retrieve, it is not entirely clear what `SettingMenus` you want/don't want?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, The `SettingMenus` is model for creating menus. About each menu is appear when the authenticated user has appropriated role which is defined in each record's role field is in user.group.

Comment: @pamer110: ok, but I don't see waht the `sub_categories__role__in` is supposed to do, so you want to see `SettingMenu`s if you have a role for that user, unless there is a subcategory that is not  having such role?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I want to see `SettingMenu` s if user has all roles are in `sub_categories`. No have a role, my mean is user should have all roles are under the `sub_categories__role`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, My problem is in accessing `related_name` in the `Jinja` code, witch have access to records are not filtered (or excluded) in the view query context maker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```py
from django.db.models import Q

nv1menus = SettingMenus.objects.filter(
    cat__company__name=company,
    cat__application="common",
    index=0,
    role__in=request.user.groups.all()
).exclude(
    ~Q(sub_categories__role__in=request.user.groups.all())
).distinct()
```

Comment: Thank you for, But my remained problem is: when in template (Jinja code) we try access the parent `related_name` the records are excluded above are accessible.

Comment: I need avoiding excluded records are accessible in context.

Answer (score 1):

You filter with a [**`Prefetch`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

nv1menus = (
    SettingMenus.objects.filter(
        cat__company__name=company,
        cat__application="common",
        index=0,
        role__user=request.user,
    )
    .prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'sub_categories', SettingMenus.objects.filter(role__user=request.user)
        )
    )
    .distinct()
)
```

this will however *not* recurse, so it will only filter *one* level.

Comment: Is not should we reffer `user..groups.all()`?

Comment: @parmer_110: but I don't see why you need to use `.exclude` here? If `role` refers to ``UserRole` and `SettingsMenus` does that as well, then we can use `role__user` to do the JOIN, which is simpler.

Comment: The `nv1menus` will send to context. I need jinja avoid referring (with `related_name`) referring the excluded records in this query.

Comment: I want In Jinja, only menus or sub-menus be accessible, if the user's groups is become member all appropriated role field groups.

Comment: @parmer_110: well the `Prefetch` object will filter the relation such that `a_settingsmenu.sub_categories.all()` will be filtered.

Comment: I have going to `exclude(~Q(sub_categories__role__in=request.user.groups.all())).distinct()` for remove records from query-set, which the user is not member of the one or more appropriated groups.

Comment: Unfortunately, after using this query, using `related_name` the not approved records are accessible. How can I avoid accessing the records are not meed the query after sending the `nv1menus` context to template?

Comment: @parmer_110: without any sample data and explaining *what* items you want to retain or filter out, it is hard to tell *wshat* you aim to achieve and thus provide relevant help...